# Stability of free radicals

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

If given a question to compare stability of free radicals, can we always check it by same parameters that we use for stability of cations (since both are electron deficient) or is there any exception to this? By parameters I mean hyperconjugation, mesomeric, resonance, inductive effects. Is there any other effect that can be added to this list?

Comment: Stereoelectronic effects. Not to say your questions here are kinda "meta-homework" - this site is "chemistry" not "how homework is done".

Comment: The thing is I am still a High school student so yes  I just deal with the basics of chemistry, and its application and problem solving (and I am not into research). But if I am showing asking a question and have shown certain effort to solve it, then what's wrong in asking it? or if am learning some new concept by asking , I think it would be harmless, since probably some questions may help future readers. Also, this site has a lot of knowledgeable people(far better than me) , and it's great learning from them since I don't have many other sources in this lockdown(covid-19).

Comment: But still if there's some better way to ask, or community guidelines that I might had not abide by, do enlighten. :)

Comment: This is rather broad. I don't think it's easily answerable; my suggestion would be to look in a book. Most organic chemistry books will have sections dedicated to radicals. The short answer is partially yes, but radicals are also stabilised by electron-withdrawing groups, and if you have both electron-donating and electron-withdrawing groups, that's [potentially even better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captodative_effect).

Comment: Well in general, I would appreciate if people tried to make their questions less homworky - yes, most of HW could be transformed into more general and useful form.

Comment: Look at nitric oxide, a *stable* free radical at room STP. https://en.wikipedia.org See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_%28chemistry%29#Stability_and_formation /wiki/Nitric_oxide